# Implement switchMap in calls order

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular6

I want to perform rest requests in order using switchMap(...)from RxJs.

Object:

```
export class Transaction {
  constructor(
    public id: string,
    public unique_id: string,
    public name: string,
    public status: string,
    public type: string,
    public created_at: Date
  ) {}
}
```

Component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-transaction-details',
  templateUrl: './transaction-details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./transaction-details.component.scss']
})
export class TransactionDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  processingLogs: ProcessingLogs = new ProcessingLogs(null, null, null, null, null);
  transaction: Transaction;

  constructor(private transactionService: TransactionService,
              private processingLogsService: ProcessingLogsService,
              private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.pipe(
      flatMap(params => {
        if(params['id']) {
          return this.transactionService.get(params['id']);
        } else {
          return of(null);
        }
      })
    ).subscribe(value => {
      if(value != null) {
        this.transaction = value;
      }
    });

    this.route.params.pipe(
      flatMap(params => {
        if (transaction.unique_id) {
          return this.processingLogsService.getProcessingLogsList(transaction.unique_id);
        } else {
          return of(null);
        }
      })
    ).subscribe(value => {
      if (value != null) {
        this.processingLogs = value;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

I tried this:

```
this.route.params.pipe(
  tap( params => {
        if(params['id']) {
          return this.transactionService.get(params['id']);
        } else {
          return of(null);
        }
      }),
      switchMap( value => this.processingLogsService.getProcessingLogsList(value.unique_id) )
  )
```

First I would like to to load `transactionService.get(params['id'])` using `id` from the http link.
Second when the Object `Transaction` is loaded I would like to load `getProcessingLogsList(transaction.unique_id)` using the `unique_id` loaded from the first request. I get multiple errors with my code attempt. 
I get empty result when I run the code.

EDIT:
I tested this but data in page is empty:

```
const transactionService = (x) => of(`transaction ${x}`);
    const processLog = (x) => of(`logged ${x}`);

    this.route.params.pipe(
      switchMap(x=> transactionService(x).pipe(
        switchMap(x=>processLog(x))
      ))
    ).subscribe(x=>console.log(x));
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you need it a chain of switchMap. Something like this:

```
const routeparams = of('1');
const transactionService = (x) => of(`transaction ${x}`);
const processLog = (x) => of(`logged ${x}`);

routeparams.pipe(
  switchMap(x=> transactionService(x).pipe(
    switchMap(x=>processLog(x))
  ))
).subscribe(x=>console.log(x));
```

Comment: Thanks dK- but I get empty result. Probably because something is missing?

Comment: I reckon you should start by making sure that your `transactionService` return a value you wanted (good old tap and console log it out) - start of by doing that without the other switch map as yet, then slowly build it up.

Comment: I want to call 2 services and get the result. Wha should be the content of subscribe?

Comment: Have a look at this (StackBlitz)[https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-nzpzbd]. It should content the result of the most inner `switchMap`

Comment: Yikes! The page you requested couldn't be found.

Comment: opps... the https is left behind. https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-nzpzbd

Comment: Nothing is printed. I don't know why.

Comment: Ok, I got the idea from the test site. What should I put in . subscribe(...)?

Comment: Essentially when you do `.subscribe(x => ...)` - `x` is the value you get back from `this.processingLogsService.getProcessingLogsList(value.unique_id)`. So, you can do whatever you want to do with it.

Comment: Can you extend the code example, please Probably I need to set `.subscribe(value => {
      if(value != null) {
        this.transaction = value;
      }
    });`?

Answer (score 0):

Following the @dK- 's answer you can chain switchMap but have you tried not imbricated way ?

```
routeparams.pipe(
    switchMap(x=> transactionService),
    switchMap(x=>processLog)
).subscribe(x=>console.log(x));
```

look here -> https://rxviz.com/v/EOe2L9ZJ

**EDITED**

ok can you try this ? this is the same but I reused your origial methods

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.route.params.pipe(
    map(params=>params['id']),
    switchMap(idParameter=> this.processingLogsService.getProcessingLogsList)
  ).subscribe(logList=>
      console.log(logList)
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you extend the answer a little bit in .subscribe?

Comment: @kevin - Chaining `switchMap` that way does not ensure `transactionService` as `Observable` if the transaction service returns a string, it will call the next `switchMap` and repeat every characters.

Comment: @dK- I don't get why the service method can return a string ? but, ok first time I didn't read all comments so I updated with originals values, no more ambiguity I think

Comment: Probably for subscribe i need to set `.subscribe(value => {
      if(value != null) {
        this.transaction = value;
      }
    });`?

Comment: yep, I don't know what your "getProcessingLogsList" function do, but if it can be null yes why not check before assign value.

Comment: I get error `ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
    at NgForOf.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/common.js.NgForOf.ngDoCheck (common.js:3152)`

Comment: First, is it working if you just look at the returned value in the subscribe ?
then, you error show a template binding error, first check your values

Comment: from your updated code I get `ERROR in src/app/panel/transaction-details/transaction-details.component.ts(58,17): error TS2345: Argument of type '(idParameter: any) => (processingLogsId: string) => Observable<ProcessingLogs[]>' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: any, index: number) => ObservableInput<{}>'.` I need send param getProcessingLogsList(transaction.unique_id) somehow.